# str.normalize not doing anything in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a pandas dataframe, loaded from a CSV, with one column that has encoded unicode characters like `\u00ca`. the `str.normalize()` method should take care of these, but it's not working, even when it works with `unicodedata.normalize`

```
import unicodedata
s = 'BC - CPE LE H\u00caTRE INC.'
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s)
>> 'BC - CPE LE HÊTRE INC.'
```

But not when it's in a pandas series.

```
import pandas as pd

names = ['BC - CPE LE H\u00caTRE INC.',
 'BC - CPE LE CHEZ-MOI DES PETITS',
 'BC GARDE MILIEU FAMILIAL DE BORDEAUX-CARTIERVILLE',
 'BC - BCGMF AHUNSTIC',
 'BC - CPE LE JARDIN DES R\u00caVES INC.',
 'BC - \FORCE VIVE\" CPE"',
 'BC - CPE GAMINVILLE INC.',
 'BC - CPE PIROUETTE DE FABREVILLE INC.',
 'B.C. ST-MICHEL',
 'BC - CPE DU PARC',
 'BC - CPE LA TROTTINETTE CAROTTEE',
 'BC - CPE DE MONTR\u00c9AL-NORD']

names = pd.Series(names)
names.str.normalize('NFKD')

>> 0                           BC - CPE LE H\u00caTRE INC.
  1                       BC - CPE LE CHEZ-MOI DES PETITS
  2     BC GARDE MILIEU FAMILIAL DE BORDEAUX-CARTIERVILLE
  3                                   BC - BCGMF AHUNSTIC
  4                BC - CPE LE JARDIN DES R\u00caVES INC.
  5                               BC - \FORCE VIVE\" CPE"
  6                              BC - CPE GAMINVILLE INC.
  7                 BC - CPE PIROUETTE DE FABREVILLE INC.
  8                                        B.C. ST-MICHEL
  9                                      BC - CPE DU PARC
  10                     BC - CPE LA TROTTINETTE CAROTTEE
  11                       BC - CPE DE MONTR\u00c9AL-NORD
  dtype: object
```

I have also tried every variation possible of `str.encode` and `str.decode` before and after `normalize`. Nothing changed.

Comment: I see the problem now. The strings are being displayed as `BC - CPE LE H\u00caTRE INC.` but in reality are stored as `BC - CPE LE H\\u00caTRE INC.`, with the unicode gettting escaped. Do you know how to decode this?

Answer (score 2):

`unicodedata.normalize` isn't doing what you think it is. `unicodedata.normalize` does not process `\u` escape sequences; it converts input into various [Unicode normalization forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Python string literal processing is what converts the `\u00ca` to an Ê character, and Python string literal processing is not applied to anything but Python string literals. The input you're reading from a CSV file does not get Python string literal processing applied. (The contents of the `names` list in your question do get string literal processing applied, so your posted code fails to reproduce your error. You really should have checked that before posting.)

Depending on the content of the file and the context of your application, decoding your input with the `unicode-escape` encoding using `codecs.decode` may be an appropriate way to handle the `\u` escapes.

Comment: This isn't strictly true; the posted code reproduces the problem in 2.7, and `str.normalize` does actually result in the correct string processing to convert the unicode literals. It, however, only does this if python2.7 has been compiled with 4-byte unicode support (otherwise, he gets the error that he's seeing).

Comment: @CJ59: On Python 2.7, `unicodedata.normalize` would have rejected `s` as an argument, since `s` would be a bytestring instead of a Unicode string on 2.7. Also, an Ê character would not have shown up in the repr of a string.

Comment: @CJ59: Funnily enough, the `Series.str.normalize` call does actually process unicode escapes on Python 2.7, but as a side effect of [a weird compatibility handling](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/339156e6da782a4c2faf395623329627f0f398a9/pandas/compat/__init__.py#L328) routine that [`Series.str.normalize`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/strings.py#L2606-L2623) calls, which decodes bytestrings with `unicode-escape`. This doesn't seem limited to 4-byte Unicode builds, but I don't have a 2-byte build handy to test with.

Comment: On further inspection, I see that the unocode characters are being displayed as `\u00ca` but in reality are stored as `\\u00ca`, with the unicode getting escaped. How do I make them unicode again? Decode/encode do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with pandas escaping the unicode character in the string. So `\u00ca` was being saved as `\\u00ca`. To decode it back, I just needed this, which @user2357112 hinted at:

`Series.str.decode('unicode-escape')`